# Task schedule using Django and Celery that fetches data from legacy database i.e. Oracle and dump to another database i.e. SQLite

Tags: python, django, oracle, sqlite, celery

Suppose I have a model in Django that represents a database table named UnfilledReturn with the following columns;  category_id and form_code configured in the SQLite in Django app. All these columns are fetched from other table in legacy database which is in Oracle(the connection is through VPN) named TRetCategory. I create a task that is capable of fetching data from TRetCategory and then dump it to the UnfilledReturn in Django using redis, and celery.

The following are codes in the Django project:-
#settings.py

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    'oracle': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'), 
        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
    }
}
# Celery beat configurations
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'

from datetime import timedelta


CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'load_task': {
        'task': 'main.tasks.load_unfilled_returns',
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=2),  
    },
}
```

#models.py

```
class UnfilledReturn(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_ID = models.IntegerField()
    FORM_CODE = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

#celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')
app = Celery('core')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings',namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

#tasks.py

```
@shared_task
def load_unfilled_returns():
    oracle_conn = connections['oracle']
    with oracle_conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT CATEGORY_ID,FORM_CODE FROM ITAX.T_RET_CATEGORY")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

    sqlite_conn = connections['default']
    with sqlite_conn.cursor() as cursor:
        for row in rows:
            CATEGORY_ID, FORM_CODE = row
            cursor.execute(
                "INSERT INTO UnfilledReturn (CATEGORY_ID, FORM_CODE) VALUES ( %s, %s)",
                [CATEGORY_ID,FORM_CODE]
            )
        sqlite_conn.commit()
```

This task is scheduled to fetch data from database in Oracle and dump it to table in SQLite. The problem is, no data is dumped when running this task but when I convert this task function to view function and create an API endpoint, the data is fetched and dumped successful.What is the best approach should I use to attain this goal.